# Store Dropdown values in cookie [ASP]

Tags: asp.net

I'm fairly new to this, so please help me out.

I am trying to store the values of 2 dropdown lists in a cookie, then have those values as the default values when the page loads again.

```
        protected void ddlSelectedIndexChange(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ddlValues");
        cookie.Values["ddlCatalogType"] = ddlCatalogType.SelectedValue;
        cookie.Values["ddlSource"] = ddlSource.SelectedValue;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(50);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

From here, where do I go? I am lost past this point, and not even sure if the above code is 100% correct.

Comment: Suggestion: Secure your cookie in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below snippet in Page_Load of the page you desired.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["ddlValues"] != null)
            {
                if (Request.Cookies["ddlValues"]["ddlCatalogType"] != null)
                {
                    string catalog = Request.Cookies["ddlValues"]["ddlCatalogType"];    
                    ddlCatalogType.SelectedIndex = ddlCatalogType.Items.IndexOf(ddlCatalogType.Items.FindByText(catalog));
                }

                if (Request.Cookies["ddlValues"]["ddlSource"] != null)
                {
                    string source = Request.Cookies["ddlValues"]["ddlSource"];
                    ddlSource.SelectedIndex = ddlSource.Items.IndexOf(ddlSource.Items.FindByText(source));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For your code, I suggest to check cookie already exist or not.

```
protected void ddlSelectedIndexChange(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (Request.Cookies["ddlValues"] == null)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ddlValues");
        cookie.Values["ddlCatalogType"] = ddlCatalogType.SelectedValue;
        cookie.Values["ddlSource"] = ddlSource.SelectedValue;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(50);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I got everything sorted out finally!